# Transform nested JS object AST to another using mapping

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, lodash, abstract-syntax-tree

I want to transform a nested JS object in AST structure into another using mappings, It can be any level deep. Any help is deeply appreciated. We can use lodash as well if that is convenient.

Motivation :- Supply data can be in several formats, I need to create standard products using different supply objects, for which we can create standard product model and several mappings for product model to supply.

If you think this problem can be solved with a better data modeling of product model or map model, I 'll highly appreciate the suggestions. The supply model is fixed nonetheless.

Data

```
const source = {
  a:1,
  b:2,
  c:7,
  children:[
    {
      a:3,
      b:7,
      d:8,
      children: [
        {
          a:6,
          b:8,
          x:4
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      a:5,
      b:3,
      c:9
    }
  ]
}
```

Mappings

```
const map = {
  c:'a',
  d:'b',
  elements: {
    identifier:'children', // which field to lookout for children
    ofType: 'map' // every child has similar structure as parent
  }
}
```

Here is the output i am expecting

```
const output = {
  c:1,
  d:2,
  elements:[
    {
      c:3,
      d:7,
      elements:[
        {
          c:6,
          d:8
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      c:5,
      d:3
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: yes and only picking attributes mentioned in the mapping to build the output

Answer (score 0):

Here is how it could be solved using tool I'm working on [Putout](https://github.com/coderaiser/putout):

```js
const defaultMap = {
    a: 'c',
    b: 'd',
    children: 'elements',
}

export const fix = (path, {options}) => {
    const map = options.map || defaultMap;
    const {name} = path.node.key;
    
    path.node.key.name = defaultMap[name];
};

export const traverse = ({push, options}) => ({
    'ObjectProperty': (path) => {
        const map = options.map || defaultMap;
        const {key} = path.node;
        
        if (map[key.name])
            push(path);
    }
});
```

Check out in [Putout Editor](https://putout.cloudcmd.io/#/gist/bc7e6d64664c5288d65e22fcb144e3e9/964d5ab8956e4b72ba0f2fee7c41a242b751aef9).

What it does is searches for `ObjectProperties` and then does the of renaming.

Notes:

- provided example is [Traverser](https://github.com/coderaiser/putout/tree/master/packages/engine-runner#traverser)
- it has `options` support from the box
- would be better to switch places of `from` and `to` in `defaultMap` it simplifies things a lot ;)